# when n is an even number, is $\{ (\cos x)^n,\cos x,\cos 2x,\cos 3x,\dots,\cos nx\}$ linear independent in Space V?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define V as the linear space of all continuous functions in real number field.We use the fundamental function operations as the rule in this space.

$\{ (\cos x)^n,\cos x,\cos 2x,\cos 3x,\dots,\cos nx\}$ is a set of elements in space V.How to find the linear correlation of these functions?

$$
2^n*cos^nx=\sum_{k=1}^n C\binom{k}{n}cos(n-2k)x
$$

Base on the following equation ,when n is a odd number, (cosx)^n is easy to linearly expressed .
But when n is a even number,constant function doesn't include in the following set.So how to confirm whether $\{ (\cos x)^n,\cos x,\cos 2x,\dots,\cos nx\}$ is linear independent ?

Comment: Please note that "find the linear correlation" is not a commonly used phrase, so some might find it confusing.

Comment: @BenGrossmann English is not my native language. So I have to learn more to make my point more understandable.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, we find that in the case where $n$ is even, $\cos^n(x)$ is linearly independent from the functions $\cos(x),\dots,\cos(n x)$.  We can do this by using the fact that, as you state, the set does not contain the constant function.

We note that each of these functions is an element of the set of functions with period $2 \pi$. Let $\langle f,g \rangle$ denote the inner product over this subspace of $C(\Bbb R)$ defined by
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(x)g(x)\,dx.
$$
Let $\mathbf 1$ denote the constant function $\mathbf 1(x) = 1$ and let  $S = \{\cos(x),\cos(2x),\dots,\cos(nx)\}$. We note that for all elements $g \in S$, we have
$
\langle \mathbf 1,g \rangle = 0.
$
It follows that $\operatorname{span}(S) \subset \mathbf 1^\perp$. On the other hand, we find that if $f(x) = \cos^n(x)$ for an even $n$, $\langle \mathbf 1,f \rangle > 0$. Thus, $f$ does not lie in $\mathbf 1^\perp$ and therefore is not an element of the span of $S$.

Comment: YES，I know how to prove the equation. When n is an even number, (cosx)^n can be linearly expressed by {1,cos2x,... ,cosnx}.However, the linear space doesn't' involve 1. So we cannot confirmed the linear dependence when n is an even number. How can we find the linear correlation when n is an even     number.

Comment: @LarryG Good point, I missed that the space doesn't include the constant function.

Comment: @LarryG See my latest edit. The functions are linearly independent in the case that $n$ is even.

Comment: I doubt how to prove the linear independence of {cos2x,cos4x,…,cosnx}

Comment: @LarryG In fact, the same idea can be used: if we define $g_k(x) = \cos(kx)$, then we find that
$$
\langle g_j,g_k \rangle = \begin{cases}\pi & j=k\\ 0 & j \neq k.\end{cases}
$$
In other words, the functions are mutually orthogonal and are therefore linearly independent.